# How to create recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, realm, android-recyclerview

How do I display my list from ActivityMain to Realm? How to add with EditText on Main2Activity a new player in Realm?

P.S. 
Need to create a class App extends Application?
i spent 4 days end no result

class MainActivity: Here I want add  List players in Realm
, it's default.

```
    package com.first.anew;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import io.realm.Realm;
    import pl.fanfatal.swipecontrollerdemo.R;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private PlayersDataAdapter mAdapter;
        SwipeController swipeController = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            setPlayersDataAdapter();
            setupRecyclerView();



        }


        private void setPlayersDataAdapter() {

            List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();



            Intent i = getIntent();
            String text = i.getStringExtra ( "TextBox" );
            if (text != null) {
                Player pl = new Player();
                pl.setName(text);
                players.add(players.size(), pl);
            }


            try {
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("players.csv"));

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
                reader.readLine();
                String line;
                String[] st;



                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    st = line.split(",");
                    Player player = new Player();
                    player.setName(st[0]);

                    players.add(player);


                }



            } catch (IOException e) {


            }

            mAdapter = new PlayersDataAdapter(players);

        }


        private void setupRecyclerView() {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            swipeController = new SwipeController(new SwipeControllerActions() {
                @Override
                public void onRightClicked(int position) {
                   // mAdapter.players.remove(position);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mAdapter.getItemCount());
                }
            });

            ItemTouchHelper itemTouchhelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeController);
            itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
                @Override
                public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                    swipeController.onDraw(c);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_cat1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

class Main2Activity: Here with the EditText i add new player in Realm (List players)

```
package com.first.anew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import io.realm.Realm;
import pl.fanfatal.swipecontrollerdemo.R;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent ( Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class );
                        intent.putExtra ( "TextBox", editText.getText().toString() );
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }


        );
    }


}
```

class Player

```
package com.first.anew;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class Player extends RealmObject {

    private String  name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

class PlayersDataAdapter: Adapter without Realm

```
package com.first.anew;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import pl.fanfatal.swipecontrollerdemo.R;


class PlayersDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayersDataAdapter.PlayerViewHolder> {
    public List<Player> players;

    public class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;

        public PlayerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        }
    }

    public PlayersDataAdapter(List<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);

        return new PlayerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Player player = players.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(player.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return players.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite unclear what exactly are you asking here. Could you please EDIT your question and rephrase it? (Please avoid posting comments on your own question)  Thanks

Comment: [The official samples show you how to do this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/4c4afb36313791dda975868a2c1f31763fe325b5/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java#L32-L67)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so i try to explain my Q .the question is how to add a list from MainActivity to Realm ? and How i can add by EditText from Main2Activity a new player in Realm data base? i suppose that i should use adapter but didn't know how it to realize it.

Comment: You seem to be reading from a CSV to fill up your data. Realm's [official samples *also* show you how to do this.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/4c4afb36313791dda975868a2c1f31763fe325b5/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/MyApplication.java#L41-L71)